# How to provide firebase credentials while running the application

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a counseling chatbot application (android). I am storing sensitive user data in Firebase Realtime Database. While setting up the firebase SDK I am required to store a `google-services.json` file inside the Android Studio project, which contains firebase project authentication information.

The application will be used by different groups/enterprises, so I don't want to store all of their info in a central firebase database. I want each group to be able to provide its own database which can store information about all its employees.

**Is there any way to provide firebase database credentials after the app is compiled and running? so that each group can connect their own firebase database to the app.**

Also, if not Firebase Realtime Database, please suggest any other database service which is more suited to this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

> The application will be used by different groups/enterprises, so I don't want to store all of their info in a central Firebase database. I want each group to be able to provide its own database which can store information about all its employees.

If you don't want to store all the data in a single database, then I recommend you create a new instance for each group/enterprise. So you can [connect your app to multiple database instances](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding). This mechanism is also called data sharding, and it's the best way in which you can optimize the performance and scalability of your app.

Comment: Hey Lupin. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?